# ReactJs: How to preload assets and components so that they can be shown when disconnected from internet

Tags: javascript, reactjs

The application checks when a certain websocket goes offline. 
Whenever this happens, a few popups will be shown in order and each with their own functionality. 
This is the only time these popups will be shown.

- On some browsers, not all images will be shown on the popups
- On other browsers, the 2nd popup will not be shown

I cannot prerender anything on the server side. Everything is hosted in an iframe by another party and I have no control over the parent framework or any of the servers.

I have no idea how to start tackling this issue.

- Should I just render it anyway and hide it in css? (will the browser load / show it or is it optimized to now even download the images)
- Should I create the component but update the z-index?
- ... a better solution?